# NHibernate + Criterias + DetachedCriteria

Tags: nhibernate

I got this a problem, I need translate this SQL Query to Criteria, but I´m getting some troubles, any one can give a hand?

SELECT * FROM Ref
INNER JOIN Product Prod on Ref.id = Prod.id_referencia 
AND Prod.ProdDtAlteracao = (SELECT MAX(Prod2.ProdDtAlteracao) FROM Product Prod2 WHERE Prod.ProdCod = Prod2.ProdCod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Ref has a bag/list property called "products" which maps to Product...

```
session.CreateCriteria<Ref>("r")
    .CreateAlias("products", "p", InnerJoin)
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("p.ProdDtAlteracao", DetachedCriteria.For<Product>("p2")
        .SetProjection(Projections.Max("p2.ProdDtAlteracao"))
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("p.ProdCod", "p2.ProdCod"))))
    .List<Ref>();
```

query would look like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM Ref 
    INNER JOIN Product Prod on Ref.id = Prod.id_referencia 
    WHERE Prod.ProdDtAlteracao = (
            SELECT MAX(Prod2.ProdDtAlteracao) 
            FROM Product Prod2 
            WHERE Prod.ProdCod = Prod2.ProdCod
        )
```